# Are You Allowed to Buy Groceries While in Self Quarantine? [Canada]

Tags: canada, travel, covid-19

Canadians returning to Canada must self-quarantine for 14 days upon arrival. Does this mean that these people must stay in their homes, and are not allowed to leave to buy groceries? The government website is very unclear and lacks detail, and so do all of the news sites that have covered it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **In addition to the above, mandatory quarantine (self-isolate) means you must:**
>
> - go directly to your place of quarantine, without stopping anywhere, and stay there for 14 days
>
>   - do not go to school, work or other public areas and community settings
> - monitor your health for symptoms of COVID-19
> - ***arrange to have someone pick up essentials like groceries or medication for you***

Emphasis mine.

[Coronavirus disease (COVID-19): Travel restrictions and exemptions](https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/diseases/2019-novel-coronavirus-infection/latest-travel-health-advice.html#_Travellers_without_symptoms)